# Less Compiler for Linux

Tags: css, linux, compiler-construction, less

Is there a something like less.app that can compile LESS into CSS? I don't care about a GUI and don't want to install it via NPM (node.js package manager.)

Comment: Just `#apt-get install node-less`, then `$lessc styles.less`.

Comment: less.app monitors files and recompiles them automatically. If you looking for automatic compilation on Linux, here is how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671969/how-to-automatically-compile-less-into-css-on-the-server/13671970#13671970

Comment: I wonder why on earth this question was closed as "not constructive"? It's a perfectly ordinary technical question, and doesn't seem to me "likely" to "solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion" -- nor has it.

Comment: I agree with @Teemu Leisti. I can't for the life of me figure out why this was closed.

Comment: [Autoless](https://github.com/jgonera/autoless) works well for me. No GUI, works with @import and compiles in half a second. However it *is* installed via npm.

Comment: For OSX, see [Lesscss command line compiler Lessc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928028/lesscss-command-line-compiler-lessc).

Comment: For OSX, try also: `brew install npm && sudo npm install -g less`. Then it should be installed in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/less/bin/lessc`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Although [using `node.js` version is recommended](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22180/less-app-like-application/24045#24045), you can install less as ruby gem:

```
sudo apt-get install rubygems1.8 ruby1.8-dev
sudo gem install rubygems-update
sudo gem update rubygems
sudo gem install less
```

and than use `lessc` which is in `/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/lessc`, so you may want to create symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/lessc /usr/bin/
```

or add ruby gems dir to `PATH` variable:

```
export PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:$PATH
```

**EDIT:**

Using `lessc` [as described here](http://lesscss.org/#-server-side-usage):

> Command-line usage
>
> Less comes with a binary, which lets you invoke the compiler from the
>   command-line, as such:
>
> ```
> $ lessc styles.less
> ```
>
> This will output the compiled CSS to stdout, you
>   may then redirect it to a file of your choice:
>
> ```
> $ lessc styles.less > styles.css
> ```
>
> To output minified CSS, simply pass
>   the `-x` option.

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine, but all it does is display it in the terminal, how to make it output to a file ?

Comment: I've edited my answer, but it's basically unix-like output redirect to file (`lessc styles.less > styles.css`).

Comment: Is there a way to watch files

Comment: You know like watch a file for changes and automagically update the .css file

Comment: You could set up a [DVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control) repository  (I recommend Bazaar, it's quite easy) and create custom `pre_commit` hook as described [here for Bazaar](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.dev/en/user-guide/hooks.html).

Comment: @RigelGlen or you could use plain old `make`.

Comment: This answer does not work. It results in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- v8 (LoadError)`. In order to fix it, add one more essential ruby gem with the following command: `sudo gem install therubyracer"`

Comment: +1, although the path to my lessc gem was slightly different on ubuntu 12.04 (`/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/less-2.2.2/bin/lessc`)

Comment: how to tell compiler to auto compile or WATCH ? with linux terminal

Comment: @STEEL Please post a new, separate question about that.

Comment: @Xaerxess I justs did that here, can u please help. http://askubuntu.com/questions/349855/less-css-compiler-help-in-terminal

Comment: @Xaerxess here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003328/less-css-compiler-help-in-terminal

Comment: If you're asked to install gem 'therubyracer' to use Less, try: `sudo gem install therubyracer`.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use this : http://wearekiss.com/simpless with a beautiful GUI and the watching process to automatically update the file when editing.

Comment: FWIW, this seems to be broken on ubuntu 11.10 x64 using simpleLESS 1.3

Comment: The thing is that SimpleLess is created using a Crossplatform development tool. And It has huge bugs in Linux. And now, it is being "moved to the community", so, until a community takes the project, and works on it for the linux version, I see no future on bugfixing

Comment: I think these Bugs are caused by the used Framework - Titanium - not by SimpLESS itself. I can't run any Titanium Apps on 11.10. I guess we have to wait until Titanium finally fixes it.

Comment: @LuisLoboBorobia are these bugs are fixed? Can't install SimpleLess on Ubuntu, is it a bug or I make something wrong? Simply donqloading, extracting the files nothing seems like install .sh or like that. thanks

Answer (score 8):

in fedora or centos distribution you should

```
$ sudo yum install rubygems
$ sudo yum install gcc-c++
$ sudo yum install ruby-devel     
$ sudo gem install less
$ sudo gem install therubyracer 

$ lessc yourLessFile.less > yourCssFile.css
```

Answer (score 3):

I have created a wxPython GUI app that uses node.js less compiler. It is on very early stage right now. Everyone's invited to contribute. I'm planning to make it very similar to MacOS's LessCSS App.

https://github.com/luislobo/Lobo-LessCSS-Compiler

Comment: Right now, it compiles less files on the same folder. Now I'm coding a destination path configuration / selector

Comment: It would be great if you continue this project.

Comment: I didn't have the time to continue, and found a "simpler" solution: I created compile.sh scripts, then scheduled them using incron, may be this can be helpful for you in the meantime

Answer (score 2):

One solution is a bash script discussed here: https://www.maltheborch.com/2011/09/less-app-on-linux
And available as a gist here: https://gist.github.com/malthe/1234308

It requires node, lessc, and inotify-tools (a small library for watching changes to files.)  Simply throw it in a file, make that file executable, then run it with a directory as the argument.

The downside is that while it will watch a directory recursively, it will only compile whichever file was modified--it doesn't have the ability to automatically compile the less files which import the one you're working on.

**Update:** A similar option is this slightly more complex bash script which adds a few features: http://code.krml.fr/less.app

Comment: The links you've provided are dead :(

Answer (score 1):

I know, that this answer is quite "too late", but I recently tried to build a simple gui for linux. With JAVA and the less.js it is not just linux, but cross-platform.
Simpless isn't supported anymore (since 1.3 as written in their blog) and Crunch uses Adobe Air which is also out of date.

here is my project: http://project.splashfish.de/Le-css/

Answer (score 0):

For java there is an open source tool called [wro4j](http://alexo.github.com/wro4j/).

It uses rhino as underlying engine for compiling less to css, but can also use node.js if it is supported on your environment.