# How to automatically compile LESS into CSS on the server?

Tags: css, linux, events, less, iowait

Friend designer of mine was compiling his LESS file manually and uploading it with Coda (Remote Site) spending lots of precious time. He asked me:

Is it possible to automatically detect file change on the Linux server and compile without delay at all?

Comment: If you're using Drupal, [Less](https://drupal.org/project/less) module automatically process any less files for you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have made a script and I publish the details:

- Easy to use for designers
- Executes LESS compiler immediately after file is saved, without consuming server resources
- Any editor capable of remote editing will work with this solution - Code, Sublime Text, Textmate

---

First, you need to install "npm" on the server by typing this into the console:

```
sudo apt-get install npm inotify-tools
sudo npm install -g less
sudo nano /usr/local/bin/lesscwatch
```

Paste the following into the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Detect changes in .less file and automatically compile into .css
[ "$2" ] || { echo "Specify both .less and .css files"; exit 1; }
inotifywait . -m -e close_write | while read x op f; do.
    if [ "$f" == "$1" ]; then.
        lessc $f > $2 && echo "`date`: COMPILED";.
    fi
done
```

Save, exit, then execute:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/lesscwatch
```

You are all done. Next time you need to work with your LESS files, you will need to open terminal (Coda has a built-in), go to the folder of your file (using cd) and execute this:

```
lesscwatch main.less main.css
```

It will output information about successful compilations or errors. Enjoy.

Comment: I found on Ubuntu, I had to install the nodejs package, and modify the lessc script (/usr/local/bin/lessc) to use nodejs as the executable, instead of node. Ie, change the top line of /usr/local/bin/lessc to #!/usr/bin/env nodejs. I like this solution; thanks for posting it!

Comment: I'm not up on my bash but my system had issues with your formatting. If I removed the end of line dots and moved `do` and `then` to their own lines (and remove semicolons), it worked swimmingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have modified @romaninsh's solution so that it will recompile when any Less files in the directory are changed.  I have also added an echo statement before compiling the Less files, to provide some validation that a change has been detected in case compilation takes a few seconds.

/usr/local/bin/lesscwatch:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     
# Detect changes in .less file and automatically compile into .css                 
[ "$2" ] || { echo "Specify both .less and .css files"; exit 1; }                  
inotifywait . -m -e close_write | while read x op f; do                            
    if [[ "$f" == *".less" ]]; then                                                
        echo "Change detected. Recompiling...";                                    
        lessc $1 > $2 && echo "`date`: COMPILED";                                                                                                                           
    fi                                                                             
done
```

This more closely mimics the behaviour of Less.app for Mac that I am used to.

When developing with Less, I usually have a bunch of files in the /style directory of my project and compile everything down into a single .css file using overrides.

Usage example:

base.less:

```
@import "overrides.less";
@import "variables.less";

body {
   ...
}
```

The usage is the same as

```
lesscwatch base.less base.css
```

Comment: In case you want the output css file to be saved in some path that contains spaces, change line 7 to `lessc $1 > "$2" && echo "\`date\`: COMPILED";`

Answer (score 2):

i'd like the bash script but I had some trouble using it with sublime wthin ubuntu 12.10 . 
well, 
the scripts did the same [Ian_Marcinkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/862708/ian-marcinkowski) does, 
but I am sure it keeps working after first event, and monitor all files (sublime text someway, use a tmp file, and do not change the original one - !?!).

```
#!/bin/bash
# Detect changes in .less file and automatically compile into .css
[ "$2" ] || { echo "Specify both .less and .css files"; exit 1; }
inotifywait -m -e close_write . | while read x op f; do
    echo $f
    echo "Change detected. Recompiling...";
    lessc $2 > $3 && echo "`date`: COMPILED";
done
```

call the script like :

```
./monitor.sh  </path/to/dir>  <main.less> <main.css>
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me :

1. instalation:
   `sudo apt install node-lessenter`

2.this is how to use it.
`lessc style.less style.css`