# Lesscss command line compiler Lessc

Tags: macos, less

Hi Im trying to get the LessCss command line compiler installed on a Mac.

I've tried

```
brew install less
Error: No available formula for less

brew install lessc
Error: No available formula for lessc

sudo npm install -g less
..Installs happily..

sudo npm install -g lessc
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lessc
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/lessc
npm ERR! 404 'lessc' is not in the npm registry.

npm install less --global
..Installs happily..

npm install lessc --global
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lessc
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/lessc
npm ERR! 404 'lessc' is not in the npm registry.
```

and all I get is

```
less js/less/style.less > style-theme.css
-bash: less: command not found

lessc js/less/style.less > style-theme.css
-bash: lessc: command not found
```

Does anyone have any experience with this?

---

I found something said my path variable might be messed up. This:

```
/bin/echo $PATH
```

gets me:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

Comment: How did you install node? Homebrew?

Answer (score 17):

the `npm` package name for `lessc` is `less`

try writing

```
sudo npm install -g less
```

Comment: Ya I did that too, I looked at the NPM page. I think my path variable might be messed up. /bin/echo $PATH gets me/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

Comment: it looks fine, make sure you have lessc in one of those paths, if not search for it and add it's directory to your `$PATH`

Comment: Thats exactly what Im doing. I've checked in /usr/local but I haven't found where Node was installed yet.

Comment: the path for `lessc` shortcut on my ubuntu machine is `/usr/local/bin/lessc` and the actual path is `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/less/bin/lessc`

Comment: Hmmm When I ls /usr/local/lib/node_modules all I get is npm... I wonder where I'm installing global modules then...

Answer (score 9):

I will try to provide a complete answer.

All commands must be executed in the **Terminal** application.

1. If you don't have it: **Install Command Line Tools for Xcode**

   `xcode-select --install`
2. If you don't have it: **Install HomeBrew**

   `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
3. If you don't have it: **Install Node.js**

   `brew install node`
4. **Install LessCSS**

   `sudo npm install -g less`

Now you can execute `lessc` commands.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen! This installs fine, but seems to build the executable with ownernship root and non-executable by group/others. Is this normal? How do I fix? ``sudo ll /usr/local/bin/lessc
lrwx------  1 root  wheel  34 Oct 29 10:11 /usr/local/bin/lessc@ -> ../lib/node_modules/less/bin/lessc``

Comment: @NicCottrell Here it does not do that. Just re-installed `lessc` on a fresh MacOS. Both binary and symlijk have `lrwxr-xr-x`. You can fix it by doing:
`sudo chmod -h 755 /usr/local/bin/lessc /usr/local/lib/node_modules/less/bin/lessc`

Answer (score 1):

i`m using macOS Siera and work for me, you can try:

1. install npm using brew:

   > brew install node
2. check node and npm version using:

   > node -v
   >   npm -v

3.change user to SU using:

> sudo su

4. install less:

> npm install -g less

Good Luck.....