# LESS css compiler help in terminal

Tags: css, linux, compiler-errors, less

Im using Ubuntu 13.04 (Linux)
I have installed node, and npm. With npm I downloaded less via terminal.

**Im using this on my simple HTML/CSS project. pure frontend. its not a Ruby or nodejs project.**

And when I do

```
lessc styles.less styles.css -x -w
```

in terminal, it compiles and compresses the code, but doesn't **watch** the file for changes, since Im expecting LESS to auto compile and refresh the page automatically. So, if I do any changes in my styles.less, every-time I have to go to terminal and enter the command to compile the less css.

Also, the compiler does NOT even show any **compile errors** even if I add anything on purpose, but in that case it doesn't compiles.

Please guide me on how to achieve the above. This is my first day with LESS CSS.

Answer (score 2):

If you type `lessc help` you will see that there is no argument -w or --watch. What you can do is to use a build system like [GruntJS](http://gruntjs.com/) with an extension like [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) and have that monitor your less files and build the css on change.

Comment: thanks for replying. But is there anything for ubuntu like this one http://wearekiss.com/simpless

Comment: You can use https://npmjs.org/package/watch-lessc which wraps watch. I am not really aware of any GUI for building it, I stick to the console, so I am OS independent. I think you can download simpleLess and build it on your own.

Answer (score 1):

I did this with help of @Oil on ubuntu forums.

In terminal,
1. install `sudo apt-get install inotify-tools`

1. then simply CD to the css folder.
   and run below lines together:

   `while inotifywait -r styles.less; do
       lessc -x styles.less styles.css;
   done`